# recurrence solving

Tags: math, complexity-theory, recurrence

I need to find the complexity of the current recurrence:

```
T(n) = 1/(T(n-1) + 1) + 1
```

thanks in advance for any idea or link with useful information

Comment: Off topic - not a programming question.

Comment: @Oded - why not? I am guessing the OP has a recursive algorithm and wants to calculate its complexity.

Comment: @Oded: why? it is about complexity of the algorithms.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan - I am assuming he needs help with his mathematics. The fact is, there is _nothing_ about programming in this question, it is pure maths.

Comment: @Henk: What if it is? Then only the homework tag should be added. And since it's not please have some respect for the OP and answer the question if you can. If you can't why do you care?

Comment: @Oded: You know, calculating the sum of 1...n is a math formula, but it's also a legitimate programming question. There is no such thing as 'pure math' IMHO. If some piece of math, like this one, is heavily used in algorithms then this is already a programming question. Programming is not coding, you know

Comment: I'm not sure that this recurrence makes sense.  It's stating that the cost of the `n`-th recurrence is *less* than that for the `(n-1)`-th recurrence (assuming `T(n-1) > 1`)...

Comment: @Armen: It is custom for the OP to mark it as homework. And it should be mentioned, at least in a comment, to stop people from providing complete answers.

Comment: @rookie, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Henk: Totally agree. But if it is not marked as homework then we assume it is not, unless there is a strong reason to believe otherwise. I don't see why this should necessarily be homework

Comment: @Henk Holterman: master method is not working here, so I tryed the method of iteration,  but it doesn't seem to work, I think I need to know some trick here...

Comment: Following on from my previous comment... I think the only meaningful way this relationship can be satisfied is if the complexity is `O(1)`...

Comment: @Armen: because it really smells like homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comments above...

This doesn't make sense as a real-world recurrence relationship.  `T(n)` denotes the runtime to solve a problem of size `n`; `T(n-1)` denotes the runtime for size `(n-1)`.  Given that you must solve the problem for size `(n-1)` before you can solve for size `n` (otherwise it wouldn't be a recursion), the runtime must necessarily be [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity) as `n` increases.

However, your expression oscillates up and down with `n`; this doesn't make sense.

The only way this expression could ever make sense is if we assume that `T(n)` is constant with `n`, so that there is no oscillation.  It turns out that there is a constant value that allows this to happen, just set `T(n) = T(n-1)`, and solve.  (Note that this is equally meaningless; we don't generally talk about *absolute* values of `T(n)`.)